# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider - I think I've checked the obvious stuff

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

effectively in my unit test beforeEach I have

```
var moduleName = 'gameModel';
var providerName = 'gameConstants';
angular.module(moduleName);
inject(function($injector) {
    $injector.get(providerName);
});
```

I've copy-pasted the module name and the provider name in from the module and constant implementation itself, so I'm pretty sure it isn't a typo in the names. Karma is loading files in this order:

1. angular
2. angular-mocks
3. The js file containing the module "gameModel" - which has no dependencies
4. The js file containing the constant provider "gameConstants" - which has no dependencies
5. The unit test file .js.

I *think* this covers the obvious stuff (thought I'm fairly new to angular) - the names seem to be OK and nothing should be trying to be injected before it should. But I'm still getting the unknown provider exception.

I've been on this a few hours and have discovered this weirdness I don't understand:

```
var moduleName = 'gameModel';
var providerName = 'gameConstants';
angular.module(moduleName);
inject(function($injector){
    console.log('Inject method, injector has provider: ', $injector.has(providerName));
    console.log('First provider name: ', angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue[0][2][0]);
});

var fooInjector =  angular.injector([moduleName]);
console.log('Explicitly rolled injector has provider: ', fooInjector.has(providerName));
```

via the inject method the `has` method returns false, but oddly *I can get the provider name out from the module itself*. If I roll my own injector (the code outside of the  `inject` method) then `has` works and I can even get at the provider. Can anyone shed some light as to why it is happening - it seems to me like I'm somehow getting a different injector in for `$inject` and `fooInjector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

I believe your issue is that you are using `angular.module` instead of either just `module` or `angular.mock.module`.

#### Long Answer

The Angular mock library creates a mock module and inject function. It must do this as the non-mocked version of module and inject must still be able to function normally so you can actually run and test your Angular code.

Therefore when you are injecting the `$injector` service into the mock inject function, the mock library has no idea about the `'gameConstants'` constant since you have not actually told the mock module about the `'gameModel'` module.

Hope that helps.